# How to get J# to work with VS 2010 and .NET 4

Tags: c#, java, .net, visual-studio, j#

*I have program in Java that I want to rewrite (GUI and some new features). I want to rewrite it in C# (mostly because of is easier to write GUI in it).*

*As the core of the program is large and is working well, I have an idea to keep it in Java as the J# code and just write a GUI and new features.*

*J# was discontinued by Microsoft several years ago, but still covers main Java syntax and libraries that I'm using in programs core.*

The problem is that J# is not supported by VS 2010 neither by .NET 4.
**Can somebody suggest a way how to make J# work with VS 2010 and .NET 4 ?** 
As I have not much experiences with VS yet I would appreciate as many details as you can provide.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps your problem can be solved with http://www.ikvm.net?

Comment: That looks very interesting... Does it work with .NET 4 and VS 2010 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile a J# library in VS2005 and add a reference to the compiled DLL in a VS2010 C# project.

However, I'm pretty sure it's impossible to use J# directly in VS2010.

You may want to look into the [Java Language Conversion Assistant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa718346.aspx).

Comment: That is fairly simple. However I would prefer some solution that would let me edit J# code in VS 2010. And I like to have all code in my the some solution.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  Try the JLCA.

Comment: How can I get JLCA ? Only if I have VS 2005 instaled ? How does it work ? Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple solution - [Calling J# code from .NET 4.0](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2011/02/calling-j-code-from-net-40.html)

thanks - dave